jboss drools is giving classnotfoundexception for agenda and rule
1.complete stack trace:
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Unable to load classSTGBilling5Update_BusinessDay.Rule_Update_BusinessDay
[0m[0m07:40:12,969 INFO  [stdout] (default task-13)     at org.drools.util.CompositeClassLoader.loadClass(CompositeClassLoader.java:110)
[0m[0m07:40:12,969 INFO  [stdout] (default task-13)     at org.drools.rule.JavaDialectRuntimeData$PackageClassLoader.loadClass(JavaDialectRuntimeData.java:540)
[0m[0m07:40:12,969 INFO  [stdout] (default task-13)     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
here STGBilling5 is category which is concept specific to our framework.
Update_BusinessDay : is agenda
Update_BusinessDay: is rule
2.we are loading drls in knowledge base object and when rule execution
occurs facts are submitted to it.
3.if enabled verbose:class the class is seen to be getting loaded but giving class not found exception
4.this occurs on some environments and on another environments it works without giving error
5.we suspect this might be related to class loading
whereclassloader is loading rule in memory and during execution drools is using different class loader.hence not able to find class.
